# equivalent for Suggested actions in Microsoft Teams

Tags: python, button, botframework, microsoft-teams

Suggested actions are not supported in teams, I get that.  People are suggesting to use cards.  I get that too.  Now let's be more specific.  I want to make a card that will behave in the same way that suggested actions behave, specifically:

1. it would not have the stupid formatting (line on top)
2. it would disappear or at least hide the buttons after the user makes a selection
3. it would send the value of a pressed button to the server, and display it in the chat window.

Here is what I have so far, and it doesn't seem to be doing the trick:

```
  actions = []
  for button in buttons:
    actions.append(
      CardAction(
        #type=ActionTypes.message_back,
        type=ActionTypes.im_back,
        value=button,
        title=button,
        text=button,
      )
    )
  
  #     card = CardFactory.adaptive_card(
  # {
  #   {
  #     "type": "Action.Submit",
  #     "title": "Click me for imBack",
  #     "data": "Text to reply in chat"
  #   }
  # }
  #     )

  card = HeroCard(buttons=actions)
  await self.global_tc.send_activity(MessageFactory.attachment(CardFactory.hero_card(card)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's been possible for a long time to *update* the content of an existing message that a bot has sent already, by passing the Action Id back as part of your payload, but there's another option more recently as well in the form of Universal Actions, which let you modify the state of the 'form' after an action has been taken. They only apply to Adaptive Cards, not Hero cards, but what you're doing in your screenshot is more applicable to Adaptive Cards anyway.

Please see here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/overview?tabs=mobile